# iOS App Store Connect is now requiring iPad screen shots even though app does not support iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

We have an iOS that is already released and only supports iPhone, not iPad.
In XCode under Deployment Targets it only has iPhone checked, not iPad.

The last release I used the same XCode version 12.4 and the build was Feb 9, 2022 and App Store Connect did not require iPad screen shots, but I made a new build and now it does?

Did Apple change something or does anyone have an idea what is going on?

Comment: Is there a warning appearing on XCode during upload or in App Store Connect ? If you can submit the app for review by leaving the iPad screenshots blank, I think that should be fine.

Comment: Make the screenshots using simulator to show how your app would look on iPad. iPad can always run iPhone apps in extended mode (that is the iPad screen has a lot of black around your app)

Comment: But 1 month ago App Store Connect did not require iPad screenshots, just had tabs for iPhone. Why is iPad now required, has something changed?

Comment: Seeing the same @James, did you figure out if this affects how the app is shown in the App Store?

Answer (score 8):

You can leave the screenshots for iPad empty and that won't block the submission.

Once approved, when accessing the app page from iPad, the iPhone screenshots will be displayed (I'm getting the 6.5'' iPhone screenshots).

The app can be downloaded and installed on iPad and it just looks like on iPhone, with most of the screen as background.